# Laraver FindOrNew with multiple parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm using laravel FindOrNew() to get an entry with two parameters, or create a new one:

```
$option = \App\Option::findOrNew(['user_id' => $this->id , 'option_name' => $optionName]);
```

I want to get an option for a user that has the name in $optionName. The problem is that it just checks for the user_id, and does not create a new one when option_name does not exist.. instead it "finds" one which does not match the $optionName value..

Can someone say what I'm doing wrong? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

You're using the wrong method. You're looking for the `firstOrNew()` method, not `findOrNew()`.

**Explanation:**

The `findOrNew()` is an extension of the `find()` method, which works on ids only. It takes two parameters, the first being the id (or array of ids) to find, and the second being the columns to retrieve. It's treating the array you've passed in as an array of ids to find.

The `firstOrNew()` method takes one parameter: an array of attributes to search for. It will turn the array into a where clause, and then call `first()` on the query builder. If no results are returned, it returns a new instance with those attributes filled in.

Comment: Thanks @patricus, I started with firstOrNew but using it on the same way gives me the exception: MassAssignmentException in Model.php line 421:
any ideas on what this is?

Comment: Solved it by adding fillable options to the model. Thanks for pointing the direction!